# Powershell: Arrays index acess and check if previous is substring to next

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to link the job to the subjob: the job is of this format for example ACGN100Q while the subjobs that are attached are sequential and of this format: ACGN-100Q-000T;ACGN-100Q-010T;ACGN-100Q-020T;ACGN-100Q-030T

In my csv file the type of this job ACGN100Q is "TechnologyInteraction" while the subjobs are of type "TechnologyService". I am developing a script that allows me to say for example that the link between ACGN-100Q-000T and ACGN-100Q-010T is of type "TrigerringRelation" and the link between ACGN100Q and ACGN-100Q-000T is of type "RealizationRelation". I need help because I can't make the link.

Here is my starting csv file :
newElements.csv

```
ID,"Type","Name","Documentation"
eb214110-2b6a-48b2-ba5a-7c13dc3bba39,"TechnologyInteraction","ACGN100Q","Begin Of JobStream"
a46681e7-19a8-4fc5-b747-09679c15ff26,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-000T","Transfert UDM (xACGN000)"
85761a09-1145-4037-a527-66a743def45f,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-010T","move fichier REF to work"
27b126fb-c708-427d-b0a6-ce4747114ac4,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-020T","w_read_account"
bb0c5e42-5fad-4bd9-8ee9-f41d0b824e82,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-030T","w_read_referential"
0b8b76e3-62fa-4527-9f05-2eb4dbaa8e97,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-040T","w_load_CompanyGroup"
1f487986-3cac-4af8-bda2-6400a1c71f48,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-050T","w_load_Company"
```

And I want to get a file that looks like this:
relation.csv

```
"ID","Type","Name","Documentation","Source","Target"
"New ID","RealizationRelationship","","","eb214110-2b6a-48b2-ba5a-7c13dc3bba39","a46681e7-19a8-4fc5-b747-09679c15ff26"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","a46681e7-19a8-4fc5-b747-09679c15ff26","85761a09-1145-4037-a527-66a743def45f"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","85761a09-1145-4037-a527-66a743def45f","27b126fb-c708-427d-b0a6-ce4747114ac4"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","27b126fb-c708-427d-b0a6-ce4747114ac4","bb0c5e42-5fad-4bd9-8ee9-f41d0b824e82"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","bb0c5e42-5fad-4bd9-8ee9-f41d0b824e82","0b8b76e3-62fa-4527-9f05-2eb4dbaa8e97"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","0b8b76e3-62fa-4527-9f05-2eb4dbaa8e97","1f487986-3cac-4af8-bda2-6400a1c71f48"
```

```
$result= @()

function linkedRelationCsvToElementsCsv{
    #relations.csv headers are ID,"Type","Name","Documentation","Source","Target"
      $Type=@()
      $Name=@()
      $ID=@()
      $Documentation=@()
    #$pattern="^(WEBX|DWHS|COGN|CLOT|CLAI|BTRE|BISI|BDDO|ARXL|AGSO|AGPC|ACTO|FNET|ARX|AGS|INF|CLA|MEM|SWA|REX)-"
    $newElementsCsv=Import-CSV $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\newElements.csv |sort ID,"Type","Name","Documentation"  -Unique
    # Check if type is TechnologyInteraction or TechnologyService and link :TechnologyService to TechnologyInteraction and TechnologyInteraction to TWS id's
    ForEach ($line in  $newElementsCsv){
     $Type += $line.Type
      $Name += $line.Name
      $ID +=$line.ID
      $Documentation += $_.Documentation
        #Search for element type in elements.csv
       for( $index=0; $index -le  $Name.length-1; $index++){

        if($Type[$index] -eq 'TechnologyInteraction'  -or $Type[$index] -eq 'TechnologyEvent' ){
        Write-Warning "Case type TechnologyInteraction founded, new type of RealizationRelationship created  "
    # if the job is of type "TechnologyInteraction" or "TechnologyEvent", we link it to the TWS id's(TechnologyCollaboration,ef2f510b-924b-439d-8720-0183c7294eb3) in archi.
        $newArrayResult= New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); "Type"="RealizationRelationship"; "Name"=$Name[$index]; "Documentation"=$Documentation[$index]; "Source"="ef2f510b-924b-439d-8720-0183c7294eb3"; "Target"=$ID[$index]}
            $result = $result + $newArrayResult
    }elseif ($Type[$index][0].Type -eq 'TechnologyService'  -and$Type[$index][1].Type -eq 'TechnologyService' ){
    Write-Warning "Case type TechnologyService founded, new type of TriggeringRelationship created  "
        $newArrayResult2 = New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); "Type"="TriggeringRelationship"; "Name"=""; "Documentation"=""; "Source"=$line[$index][0].ID; "Target"=$line[$index][1].ID}
        $result = $result + $newArrayResult2
    }
    }
    
    }
    $result |Select-Object -Property ID,"Type","Name","Documentation","Source","Target"| Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\relation.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 
  
}linkedRelationCsvToElementsCsv # Call the function

> the elseIf() not return value.

Thanks you in advance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code generates exactly the output you want for exactly the input you've given. There might be unexpected edge cases, so you should write some tests (e.g. with Pester) to confirm it behaves how you want it to in those edge cases.

The key is that the output for any row includes the ID of the previous row as well as the current row, so we keep the previous row in a variable during the foreach loop so we can inspect it when we process the next row, and the Type in the output just depends on the Type of the previous row.

Note that I've also moved the conversion to / from csv out of the main function so it's easier to unit test the function in isolation.

```
function ConvertTo-ElementItems
{

    param
    (
        [object[]] $Relations
    )

    $jobTypes = @( "TechnologyInteraction", "TechnologyEvent" );
    $subTypes = @( "TechnologyService" );

    $previousItem = $null;

    foreach( $item in $Relations )
    {

        if( $item.Type -in $jobTypes )
        {
            # start of a new job, but don't output anything
        }
        elseif( $item.Type -notin $subTypes  )
        {
            # not a subjob type that we recognise
            throw "unrecognised subjob type '$($item.Type)' for subjob '$($item.ID)'";
        }
        elseif( $null -eq $previousItem )
        {
            # we've got a subjob, but there was no previous job or subjob
            throw "no preceding item for subjob '$($item.ID)'";
        }
        elseif( $previousItem.Type -in $jobTypes )
        {
            # this is the first subjob after the parent job
            new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
                "ID"            = "New ID"
                "Type"          = "RealizationRelationship"
                "Name"          = "";
                "Documentation" = ""
                "Source"        = $previousItem.ID
                "Target"        = $item.ID
            });
        }
        else
        {
            # the preceding item was a subjob as well
            new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
                "ID"            = "New ID"
                "Type"          = "TriggeringRelationship"
                "Name"          = ""
                "Documentation" = ""
                "Source"        = $previousItem.ID
                "Target"        = $item.ID
            });
        }

        $previousItem = $item;

    }
  
}
```

And here's an example of using the function:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest";

$inputCsv = @"
ID,"Type","Name","Documentation"
eb214110-2b6a-48b2-ba5a-7c13dc3bba39,"TechnologyInteraction","ACGN100Q","Begin Of JobStream"
a46681e7-19a8-4fc5-b747-09679c15ff26,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-000T","Transfert UDM (xACGN000)"
85761a09-1145-4037-a527-66a743def45f,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-010T","move fichier REF to work"
27b126fb-c708-427d-b0a6-ce4747114ac4,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-020T","w_read_account"
bb0c5e42-5fad-4bd9-8ee9-f41d0b824e82,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-030T","w_read_referential"
0b8b76e3-62fa-4527-9f05-2eb4dbaa8e97,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-040T","w_load_CompanyGroup"
1f487986-3cac-4af8-bda2-6400a1c71f48,"TechnologyService","ACGN-100Q-050T","w_load_Company"
"@

$expectedCsv = @"
"ID","Type","Name","Documentation","Source","Target"
"New ID","RealizationRelationship","","","eb214110-2b6a-48b2-ba5a-7c13dc3bba39","a46681e7-19a8-4fc5-b747-09679c15ff26"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","a46681e7-19a8-4fc5-b747-09679c15ff26","85761a09-1145-4037-a527-66a743def45f"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","85761a09-1145-4037-a527-66a743def45f","27b126fb-c708-427d-b0a6-ce4747114ac4"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","27b126fb-c708-427d-b0a6-ce4747114ac4","bb0c5e42-5fad-4bd9-8ee9-f41d0b824e82"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","bb0c5e42-5fad-4bd9-8ee9-f41d0b824e82","0b8b76e3-62fa-4527-9f05-2eb4dbaa8e97"
"New ID","TriggeringRelationship","","","0b8b76e3-62fa-4527-9f05-2eb4dbaa8e97","1f487986-3cac-4af8-bda2-6400a1c71f48"
"@;

$relations = $inputCsv | ConvertFrom-Csv;
$elements = ConvertTo-ElementItems -Relations $relations;
$outputCsv = ($elements | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join "`n";

if( $outputCsv -ne $expectedCsv )
{
    throw "output csv doesn't match expected csv";
} else {
    write-host "output csv matches expected csv";
}
```